# How to make the domain name with a capital letter?

Tags: .htaccess

How to make the domain name with a capital letter?

like `Surname.com` instead of `surname.com`

Comment: What do you mean? Users can type either (since domain names, unlike the rest of the URL, are case insensitive), what is the effect you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I imagine the effect would be to have something like mybeautifulsite.com rather show up as MyBeautifulSite.com. Looks and reads nicer. I am searching for how to do this right now, in case yall know how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, because [domain names are case-insensitive](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4343.txt). In other words: `Surname.com` is **exactly the same** as `surname.com`.

And the *canonical* version is the lower-case name (i.e. if you enter "Surname.com" in your browser, it will automatically be converted to "surname.com").

Answer (score 3):

Whilst DNS itself is case-insensitive, at least one search engine allows you to declare preferred case in search results: Yandex.

[image: Yandex - Case of the site name]

The [Case of the site name](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/search-results/name-case.xml) tool lets you set preferred capitalisation in certain cases. This can be accessed in [Yandex.Webmaster](https://webmaster.yandex.com/) under `Appearance in search results` > `URL letter case`.

I've set this for a few of my sites and it's quite nice to see.